# How to overwrite previous output in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script, that outputs top most CPU intensive processes every second to the terminal.

```
tmp=$(ps -e -eo pid,cmd,%mem,%cpu,user --sort=-%cpu | head -n 11)
printf "\n%s\n" "$tmp[pid]"
```

I know that I can move my cursor to the predeclared position, but that fails every time terminal is not cleared. 
I could also just go to the beginning of the line and write over it, but that again makes a problem when current output is shorter that the previous and when the number of lines is not the same as it was at the previous output.

Is there a way to completely erase the previous output and write from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can clear a part of the screen before each iteration (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297502/clear-half-of-the-screen-from-the-command-line), but the function *watch* does it for you. Try:

```
watch -n 1 "ps -e -eo pid,cmd,%mem,%cpu,user --sort=-%cpu | head -n 11"
```